# Can't add new row to a datatable [c#]

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset, datarow

I have a dataset, which is stored in XML file. When application starts and XML file doesn't exists yet, I want to add some rows to my dataset and save it in XML. I use following code to do it:

```
        partiesDb = new Parties();

        //...
        DataTable partyDsTable = partiesDb.Tables["party"]; //partiesDb is DataSet object
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = partyDsTable.NewRow(); // HERE THE CODE STOPS
            row["sth"] = sth;
            row["sth"] = "0";
            row["id"] = "1";
            if (!partyDsTable.Rows.Contains(row))
            {
                partyDsTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(partyDsTable.Rows[0]["sth"].ToString());
        partiesDb.WriteXml(path);
```

and nothing happens. Even messagebox doesn't show. The function just stop when creating a new row, and I don't know why. Can you help me?

[EDIT]:
This code works fine:

```
            partiesDb = new Parties();
            DataTable dsTable = partiesDb.Tables["party"];
            DataRow dsRow = dsTable.NewRow();
            dsRow["name"] = "";
            dsRow["id"] = "";
            dsRow["votes"] = "";
            dsTable.Rows.Add(dsRow);
            partiesDb.WriteXml(partiesDbPath);
```

I don't know why this works, but when I add loop it doesnt...

Comment: Where is that code located?  If the XML doesnt exist yet, does the table?  Is it null?

Comment: Yes, the table is null when the program starts and its defined in designer. The code is located in function, which is called in form constructor.

Comment: @g2556 you can't add something to a null variable.

Comment: Put the code in a button click for development and you'll see the error - NRE

Comment: @g2556 you really need to add the exception message and inner exception (if any) to your question. I doubt the application just "stops".

Comment: @g2556 does it error out the first time it enters the loop, or the next time?

Comment: First time. There's no any error, just the loop doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @g2556 what does "the loop doesn't work any more" mean? You need to provide as much description as possible if you want to receive meaningful help. Right now, I can't tell what the problem is.

Comment: Just lines after "crash" line don't execute. If you put MessageBox.Show(..) after crash line it won't show.

Comment: @g2556 great, so now we know it crashes. So what exception do you get? Do you have a try/catch, and do you display the exception that is thrown?

Comment: I put crash word in "". Its not a crash at all, because there is NO EXCEPTION, the code just stops executing. Look at EDIT in my question please.

Comment: Put the code in a button click and you will see the exception!  Some exceptions get "eaten" when thrown when the form is being created.

Comment: I did it, still no exception... Im being frustrated

Comment: @g2556 ok, at runtime what is the value of `size` when it reaches the loop?

Comment: size is always 2 in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can't add something to a null variable. So, you need to instantiate the `partyDsTable` if it is null.

```
DataTable partyDsTable = partiesDb.Tables["party"]; //partiesDb is DataSet object

if(partyDsTable == null) // instantiate it
    partyDsTable = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    ....
```

Comment: I have just edited the question. I'm not sure if the datatable is null, because I've instantiated the dataset before I was trying to add rows

Comment: @g2556 you really need to add the exception message and inner exception (if any) to your question. I doubt the application just "stops".

Comment: There's no any exception. The application doesnt stop at all, I can still use controls on form.

Comment: @g2556 then what exactly is the problem here? what does "here the code stops" mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable partyDsTable = partiesDb.Tables["party"]; //partiesDb is DataSet object
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)// "size" does not look like it's set to anything. If "size" is 0, then the loop will not loop. 
    {

            partyDsTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {sth,"0","1"});//you should probably make the columns into the correct type if you are using integers.

    }
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(partyDsTable.Rows[0]["sth"].ToString());
    partiesDb.WriteXml(path);
```

Comment: Size is not 0. I'm not using integers.

Comment: @g2556 then why are you comparing `size` to an integer if it isn't an integer?

Comment: I meant the type of properties in rows arent integers.

Comment: Size is obviously an integer (***INT*** I=0;i<size...) what I'm saying is that if size isn't set to something above zero elsewhere, your loop will not process. "size" needs to be set above zero somewhere in your code for your loop to work.

Comment: Most likely, you want "size" to be the length of the array you are inputting, or the Count of the list you are inputting. You haven't shown us the beginning of your method, so I can't tell you what that might be, but unless you set size to be something, your loop will not work.

Comment: Can you add the beginning of the method to show where you set the value of the integer variable size?

Comment: The size is always above integer. I will add whole method on pastebin, wait a moment please. http://pastebin.com/tDcauYGp

Comment: I don't think you're understanding me. loops count from the first integer to the second integer. In your case, the loop will count from 0 to whatever value you have set for size. Normally, that variable wouldn't be a separate integer variable, but rather the count of your input (input_array.Length or input.List.Count, etc.) The fact that you are using an independent variable there suggests that you may not have set the value of size to be higher than zero. If size is zero, your loop will not work, because it is counting from 0 to 0. "size" doesn't mean anything on its own so you'd have to set

Comment: In reading the other comments, I'm now totally convinced your problem is that "size" is set to zero. You need to be using the count/length of your input, or you need to manually set the integer variable size to be equal to the count of your input

Comment: Its always counting from 0 to 2 in my case (size=2).

Comment: That is not a very large number - especially since you are checking for row duplicates. Try using your input values directly, or increasing size to 100 manually and see what happens.

Comment: Just set size to 100. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you create a class with fields that match the items in your database table, you can do all kinds of things with reflection to make usre your data is always good:

```
public static DataTable create_DataTable_From_Generic_Class(Type t)
    {
        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        FieldInfo[] fI = t.GetFields();
        for(int i = 0; i < fI.Length; i++)
        {
            DataColumn dC = new DataColumn(fI[i].Name, fI[i].FieldType);
            d.Columns.Add(dC);
        }
        return d;
    }
    public static object[] Create_Datatable_Row_From_Generic_Class(Type t, object instance,DataTable dt)
    {

        FieldInfo[] f = t.GetFields();
        object[] ret = new object[f.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = t.GetField(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName).GetValue(instance);

        }
        return ret;

    }
    public static List<string[]> getParams(Type type, bool convertToSQL)
    {


        List<string[]> ret = new List<string[]>();
        Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (FieldInfo prop in type.GetFields())
            properties.Add(prop.Name, prop.FieldType);
        foreach (string key in properties.Keys)
        {
            string[] r = { key, properties[key].ToString().Replace("System.", "") };
            ret.Add(r);
        }
        if (convertToSQL)
        {
            return convertFromNetToSQLDataTypes(ret);

        }
        else
        {
            return ret;
        }
    }
    private static List<string[]> convertFromNetToSQLDataTypes(List<string[]> list)
    {
        foreach (string[] data in list)
        {
            data[1] = data[1].Replace("Int16", "tinyint");
            data[1] = data[1].Replace("Int32", "int");
            data[1] = data[1].Replace("Int64", "bigint");
            data[1] = data[1].Replace("Double", "float");
            data[1] = data[1].Replace("Boolean", "tinyint");
            data[1] = data[1].Replace("Double", "float");
            data[1] = data[1].Replace("Long", "bigint");
            data[1] = data[1].Replace("String", "varchar(100)");
        }
        return list;
    }
    public static object[] sql_Reader_To_Type(Type t, SqlDataReader r)
    {
        List<object> ret = new List<object>();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            FieldInfo[] f = t.GetFields();
            object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
            {
                string thisType = f[i].FieldType.ToString();
                switch (thisType)
                {
                    case "System.String":

                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToString(r[f[i].Name]));
                        break;
                    case "System.Int16":
                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToInt16(r[f[i].Name]));
                        break;
                    case "System.Int32":
                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToInt32(r[f[i].Name]));
                        break;
                    case "System.Int64":
                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToInt64(r[f[i].Name]));
                        break;
                    case "System.Double":
                       // Console.WriteLine("converting " + f[i].Name + " to double");
                        double th;
                        if (r[f[i].Name] == null)
                        {
                            th = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (r[f[i].Name].GetType() == typeof(DBNull))
                            {
                                th = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                th = Convert.ToDouble(r[f[i].Name]);
                            }
                        }
                        try { f[i].SetValue(o, th); }
                        catch (Exception e1)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("can't convert " + f[i].Name + " to doube - value =" + th);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "System.Boolean":
                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToInt32(r[f[i].Name]) == 1 ? true : false);
                        break;
                    case "System.DateTime":
                        f[i].SetValue(o, Convert.ToDateTime(r[f[i].Name]));
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception("Missed data type in sql select in getClassMembers class line 73");

                }
            }
            ret.Add(o);

        }
        return ret.ToArray();


    }
```

And on and on. You can use reflection like this to create tables that match your class, create insert or procedure calls automatically, and never use an incorrect data type or get a field out of order again.

Comment: I dont understand this code... Look at edit in my question, please.